# Java - Can't print image (to paper/printer)

Tags: java, swing, printing

I am trying to print an Image using the following code, but the document simply stays in the print job queue, and refuses to print. In the (windows) print job queue I get:

> **DocumentName:** Printing an image **Status:** [Nothing] **Pages**: 1, **Size:** 2.1Mb.

This does not happen with other applications using the same printer (word, etc).

Could anyone kindly show me where is my mistake? Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //new Painter();

    MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(new JPanel());

    try {
        Image img = ImageIO.read(new File(
            "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\print.jpg"));
        tracker.addImage(img, 1);
        tracker.waitForAll();
        print(img);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void print(final Image img) {
    PrinterJob printjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printjob.setJobName("Print");

    ImgPrinter printable = new ImgPrinter(img);

    try {
        System.out.println("Printing.");
        printable.printPage();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        System.out.println("NO PAGE FOUND." + ex);
    }
}

private static class ImgPrinter implements Printable {

    Image img;

    public ImgPrinter(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {
        if (pageNum != 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        //BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),
        //img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        //bufferedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
        g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), null);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void printPage() throws PrinterException {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        boolean ok = job.printDialog();
        if (ok) {
            job.setJobName("TEST JOB");
            job.setPrintable(this);
            job.print();
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of problem:

This happens with both hardware and software printers(XPS Writer, CutePDF, Canon printer). The hardware shows "preparing.."  on it's screen forever, and I think it wasted all it's ink, I'm not sure. If so, this code has been expensive to test....

None of these printers give an issue when printing from a word document or otherwise.

Edit: Can somebody suggest a software printer he or she has been successful with?

[Click here for the Image I am trying to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNmTe.jpg).

[Click here to see the print queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rSbp.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran a quick test, and it works fine for me. I was able to print a png image.

Chances are there is something wrong with your printer.

Did you try printing a Word Document using the Word's print option.

Are there multiple printers assigned to your machine?
You could try restarting your printer?
Restart you machine?

You could implement a print dialog box to open up. That way you can select the printer.
See this link here. The code shows how to open up the print dialog in swing.

```
 public void printPage() throws PrinterException
        {
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            boolean ok = job.printDialog();
            if (ok) {
                job.setJobName("TEST JOB");
                job.setPrintable(this);
                job.print();
            }
        }
```

This way you can make sure a printer has been selected correctly.

The other thing you can use to make sure the image does not get distorted
Instead of this line

```
g2.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, (int) pf.getWidth(), (int) pf.getHeight(), null);
```

use the following line in the inner class

```
g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), null);
```

Comment: Going to try that now. What happens if you try a large image?

Comment: @David I am editing my answer. I realized that big images were going out of the page. Directly print the image. In the code you have called "drawImage" twice. Apply drawImage directly to the image that you passed into the method

Comment: @David do you think that you can attach the Image you are trying to print with this question. Let me try it out. To be fair, I am using Linux.

Comment: I attached the image and modified the code. Please check now. Thanks!

Comment: +1 The code works for me, too; two megapixels may take a while.

Comment: @trashgod Why is it two megapixels if the image is less than 200k?

Comment: @trashgod for me the problem seems like I have a stream which has not been closed. When I check "print to file" it works and prints to a file. However neither hardware nor software printers have been successful, they say "print job in progress", forever. (I actually tested it for more than 20 minutes and it still says print job in progress. Also I have a high-end pc.). What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: @trashgod Oh and sometimes I get a NO PAGE FOUND: java.awt.print.PrinterException: The parameter is incorrect. Error. Not always though. Erratically. When this happens the print job doesn't even start. Can you suggest a software printer you tested and know it works?

Comment: 1600 * 1200 => 1,920,000 pixels; 200K sounds like nominal `jpg` compression, but the driver has to unpack it. Can it accept smaller images? Have you tried paging it using [`getSubimage()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)?

Comment: @trashgod I uninstalled the printer, reinstalled and rebooted. It worked then. Stupid windows :( Well at least maybe somebody can find the code in this thread useful.

Comment: @David yeah i figured it had something to with your printer, and not with your code. It is good you were able to figure it out.